# geom_map borders in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to produce a choropleth map using geom_map in ggplot2. I want to outline the various regions in black or some other color to distinguish between areas that are similar in color on the gradient. Using the following code I've tried to set the color to outline the areas. The code produces the map, but no borders. When I move the colour command into the aesthetic it produces the expected 'pink' borders with a legend. Any ideas why setting the color won't produce borders, but mapping will? I saw a similar discussion on the ggplot2 Google Group.

```
ggplot(subset(df, as.character(variable) == "value"), aes(map_id = id)) +
  geom_map(aes(fill = pct), colour = "black", map = ggmap) +
  expand_limits(x = ggmap$long, y = ggmap$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "antiquewhite", high = "darkred") +
  opts(title = "Title", panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "grey90"))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the polygon borders using geom_polygon.  In the code below you need to fill in the `XXXX` with a data set (`data`) and lat and long (`x` and `y`) values for each polygon.  I usually get my data from the `maps` package, not sure if this is what you did.

```
ggplot(subset(df, as.character(variable) == "value"), aes(map_id = id)) +
  geom_map(aes(fill = pct), colour = "black", map = ggmap) +
  geom_polygon(data=XXXX, aes(x=XXXX, y=XXXX), colour='black', fill=NA) +
  expand_limits(x = ggmap$long, y = ggmap$lat) +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "antiquewhite", high = "darkred") +
  opts(title = "Title", panel.background = theme_rect(fill = "grey90"))
```

Comment: Thanks Tyler. This is exactly what I was missing. I'm using a shape file that outlines outlines attendance zones for schools in a school district.

Comment: I have a question that is very similar to this one, posted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572878/geom-map-borders-in-ggplot2-revisited), in case you have time to look at it i'd be thankful for comments.

Comment: @TylerRinker Could you clarify the how getting your coordinates from the maps package would work if you want to highlight state borders in a different color. I know there is the "borders("state"), but how would you do it here using geom_polygon?

Comment: I'd suggest opening a new question.  This one is 3 years old and ggplot2 has changed since then.  Provide data in your question and be explicit in what you're after.  You can ink back to this question.