# geom_map borders in ggplot2 - revisited

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2

I have a similar problem as @Mike in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305614/geom-map-borders-in-ggplot2). The question is how to set the outline colors of the regions in a map plot.

The proposed solution there is to add a `geom_polygon` to plot over the borders. This works, as long as the whole area is plotted. When trying try to restrict to a sub-area, the polygons get drawn oddly (presumably because some vertices get dropped). Using the standard `geom_map` example:

```
# Create example data
ids <- factor(c("1.1", "2.1", "1.2", "2.2", "1.3", "2.3"))
values <- data.frame(id = ids, value = c(3, 3.1, 3.1, 3.2, 3.15, 3.5))
positions <- data.frame(
  id = rep(ids, each = 4),
  x = c(2, 1, 1.1, 2.2, 1, 0, 0.3, 1.1, 2.2, 1.1, 1.2, 2.5, 1.1, 0.3, 0.5, 1.2, 2.5, 1.2, 1.3, 2.7, 1.2, 0.5, 0.6, 1.3),
  y = c(-0.5, 0, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 1, 2.1, 1.7, 1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.1, 1.7, 2.1, 3.2, 2.8, 2.1, 2.2, 3.3, 3.2)
)

# Plot data
ggplot(values, aes(fill = value)) + 
    geom_map(aes(map_id = id), map = positions) +
    geom_polygon(aes(x,y,group=id), fill = NA, colour = 'red', data = positions) +
    expand_limits(positions) +
    ylim(0, 3)
```

A possible workaround is using the colour aesthetic in `geom_map` and then manually choose the outline color with `scale_colour_manual`, as follows:

```
ggplot(values, aes(fill = value)) + 
    geom_map(aes(map_id = id, colour = 'white'), map = positions) +
    scale_colour_manual(values=c('white')) +
    expand_limits(positions) +
    ylim(0, 3)
```

So I have two questions:

1. Why does `geom_polygon` not work properly when the axis limits are restrained?
2. Is there a more elegant solution to color the outlines than the one showed here?

Below are the plot outputs. Many thanks in advance.

[image: Did not work properly using geom_polygon]
[image: Works but is not very elegant]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you are correct as to why it doesn't work. Restricting the x or y limits using `xlim` or `ylim` clips the data prior to plotting. This will end up omitting some vertices from your polygon, so some stuff won't get plotted.

This is why there's `coord_cartesian`, which allows you to adjust the x and y limits *without* clipping the data. It will "zoom" into the correct region, rather than clipping and then plotting.

So instead of `ylim`, try `+ coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,3))`.

Comment: this works pefectly, thanks! This is a detail, but do you happen to know the answer to my second question? Why can't I use the `colour = white` aestetic in the `geom_map` function directly?

Comment: @yellowcap I don't know, mainly because I'm not sure what your specific problem is in the second case.

Comment: @yellowcap Probably far too late for this to be helpful, but you want `colour="white"` in the `geom_map` call but not in the `aes` call. It's not an aesthetic because it doesn't depend on your data. It's always just white.